# typcasting queryset to list() errors in view function - works on the shell

Tags: python, django, json, list, django-views

sI have the following code:

```
s = StoryCat.objects.filter(category=c)
ids=s.values_list('id',flat=True)
ids=list(ids)
str= json.dumps( ids )
return HttpResponse(str)
```

This runs fine when trying it with python shell.  when running it in a view function I get the following error:

list() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The list builtin has been overridden in the local scope. Here is an example of a workaround if you really want to use list():

```
def list(a, b): pass # somewhere list is redefined
try:
    c = list() # so this will fail
except TypeError as e:
    print "TypeError:", e # with this error
from __builtin__ import list as lst # but we can get back the list builtin
c = lst() # and use it without overriding the local version of list
print c
```

In your case, a minimal change would be to replace `ids=list(ids)` with

```
ids = __import__('__builtin__').list(ids)
```

which doesn't change your namespace at all, but makes me sad.

Edit: See the comment by @Alex-Laskin for a simpler one-off way of doing this.

Comment: One can use `ids=[id for id in ids]` to convert ids to list, if `list` built-in is overridden.

Comment: @alex-laskin: True, and probably the nicest way if you only need to do it once. I'd say it's better to import and rename the builtin if you're going to need it repeatedly.

Comment: Not sure I understand - The reason I typecast with list was because serializing queryset fails with error : TypeError: [335L, 468L, 481L, 542L, 559L, 567L, 609L] is not JSON serializable - Also I'm using python 2.5

Comment: I understand. The key here is your error: the real `list()` builtin doesn't take two arguments, so the `list()` you're calling can't be the builtin `list()`. Some module, class, function, etc. has redefined list()! So you need to use the real, builtin list, either indirectly through a list comprehension as suggested by Alex Laskin, or directly by importing it. Try Alex's suggestion or mine: do they solve the problem?

Comment: I didn't get an error however, the serialized string does not look correct.  The output has no seperators : 335468481542559567609697725

Comment: At what point does it have no separators? What does it look like before the `id=[id for id in ids]` line? After? After `str=json.dumps(ids)`? For me, it appears it should be `"[335, 468, 481, 542, 559, 567, 609]"` after the `str=json.dumps(ids)` line? Also, don't use `str` as a variable name, you're masking another built in function, `str()` this way!

Comment: **Much better advice:** don't ever shadow builtins! Fix this redefinition of `list` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Chris-Morgan: I assumed he didn't redefine list himself, but that it was in code he was using (or from an improvident `from module import *`); perhaps that was assuming too much.

Comment: @agf: if he's putting this in, he should fix whatever code it is necessary to fix first, not put in a messy hack. And if it's a wildcard import, then (a) get rid of *that* and (b) fix it in that module! Because this problem *will* trip people up later. It is far better fixed immediately.

Comment: @Chris-Morgan: I don't disagree, I just think sometime you have to work with code you don't understand or only need to use once, and so knowing the workaround is useful. We don't always care about the larger condition of the code.